# How to delete lines from a text until a keyword

Tags: python

I am requesting a wikipedia page that returns all the text from that website like so:

```
def my_function(addr):
    response = requests.get(addr)
    print(response.text)

my_function("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
```

Right now what im trying to do is basically delete unwanted parts, basically all text before the id with the class 'See_also'. Is there a right and easy way to do so? I could not just delete a certain amount of lines since this code is meant to work for different wiki sites.

Comment: You should use a parser like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Thats what I'm later going to use, but I do not know how to delete all text before See Also section, which I don't know if can be done using Beautiful Soup

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEX` (huraay).

```
import requests
import re

def my_function(addr):
    response = requests.get(addr)
    print(re.findall("See_also[\\s\\S]*", response.text))

my_function("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
```

Comment: the `.*` notation actually matches only first line with `See_also` this change should fix it

Comment: RegEx for HTML parsing gives me nightmares but it worked here.

Comment: You are optimistically assuming that the literal text `'See_also'` only occurs once, and only as a class ID. That is probably true in over 99.9% of the cases, but it is still an assumption of the sort that *might* fail and that can be avoided by using a proper html parser.

Comment: You can always make regex more complex to ensure it works for your use case. This is just a hint to how you can do this without any robust parser.